# How to implement System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension in a ClassLibrary-project

Tags: c#

I want to write a new Converter-class in a C#-project which inherits from the abstract class MarkupExtension
Normally MarkupExtension can be found in the library System.Windows.Markup.
In my classlibrary the library or namespace is avaible but the class MarkupExtension can't be found.
Which references do i need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
A reference to System.Xaml is needed. :)